# Either f(n) = O(g(n)) or g(n) = O(f(n))

Tags: big-o

I'm trying to prove that this is correct for any function f and g with domain and co-domain N. I have seen it proven using limits, but apparently you can also prove it without them.

Essentially what I'm trying to prove is "If f(n) doesn't have a big-O of g(n) then g(n) must have a big-O of f(n). What I'm having trouble is trying to understand what "f doesn't have a big-O of g" means.

According to the formal definition of big-O, if f(n) = O(g(n)) then n>=N -> f(n) <= cg(n) for some N and a constant c. If f(n) != O(g(n)) I think that means there is no c that fulfills this inequality for all values of n. Yet I don't see what I can do to use that fact to prove g(n) = O(f(n)). That doesn't prove that a c' exists for g(n) <= c'f(n), which would successfully prove the question.

Comment: This question is not about code.  I believe it would be suitable for the Theoretical Computer Science sister site, http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not true. Let `f(n) = 1` if `n` is odd and zero otherwise, and `g(n) = 1` if `n` is even and zero otherwise.

To say that `f` is `O(g)` would say there is a constant `C > 0` and `N > 0` such that `n > N` implies `f(n) <= C g(n)`. Let `n = 2 * N + 1`, so that `n` is odd. Then `f(n) = 1` but `g(n) = 0` so that `f(n) <= C * g(n)` is impossible. Thus, `f` is `O(g)` is not true.

Similarly, we can show that `g` is `O(f)` is not true.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, your definition of big-O is a *little* bitt off. You say:

> I think that means there is no c that fulfills this inequality for all values of n.

In actuality, you need to pick a value `c` that fulfills the inequality for **any** value of `n`.

### Anyway, to answer the question:

I don't believe the statement in the question is true... Let's see if we can think of a counter-example, where f(n) ≠ O(g(n)) and g(n) ≠ O(f(n)).

**note: I'm going to use `n` and `x` interchangeably, since it's easier for me to think that way.**

We'd have to come up with two functions that continually cross each other as they go towards infinity. Not only that, but they'd have to continue to cross each other regardless of the constant `c` that we multibly them by.

So that leaves me thinking that the functions will have to alternate between two different time complexities.

Let's look at a function that alternates between `y = x` and `y = x^2`:

```
f(x) = .2 (x * sin(x) + x^2 * (1 - sin(x)) )
```

[image: Graph 1]

Now, if we create a similar function with a slightly offset oscillation:

```
g(x) = .2 (x * cos(x) + x^2 * (1 - cos(x)) )
```

Then these two functions will continue to cross each others' paths out to infinity.

For any number `N` that you select, no matter how high, there will be an `x1` greater than `N` such that `f(x) = x^2` and `g(x) = x`. Similarly, there will be an `x2` such that `g(x) = x^2` and `f(x) = x`.

At these points, you won't be able to choose any `c1` or `c2` that will ensure that `f(x) < c1 * g(x)` or that `g(x) < c2 * f(x)`.

In conclusion, f(n) ≠ O(g(n)) does not imply g(n) = O(f(n)).

Comment: Nice explanation with example function and visualisation.